# Refactor array_key_exists in PHP8

Tags: php, php-8

Having just attempted to upgrade from PHP 7.4.33 to 8.0.27 I have encountered the following error on a key page:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1981 in
> drivers_standing_table.php on line 56
>
> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_key_exists():
> Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given in
> drivers_standing_table.php:56

1981 is an id (int) associated with a record in the database. For example, in this case a competitor has an id of 1981.

Line 56 of drivers_standing_table.php (and slightly thereafter) looks like this:

```
// LINE 56:
if (array_key_exists($round, $shared_drivers[$driver_id])) {

  $lender_id = $shared_drivers[$driver_id][$round];
  $lender_race_result = $drivers_race_result_array[$lender_id][$round][0];
  $cls_name = $drivers_race_result_array[$lender_id][$round][1];
  $race_result = $drivers_race_result_array[$driver_id][$round][0];

  if (array_key_exists($round, $drivers_race_result_array[$driver_id])) {     ?>
    <td align='center' style="background: orangered;">
        <?php echo $race_result . '/' . $lender_race_result; ?>
    </td>
  <?php
    $exit_flag = true;
    $i++;
  } else {
  ?>
    <td align='center' class='<?php echo $cls_name; ?>'>
        <?php echo $lender_race_result; ?>
    </td>
  <?php }
}
```

The error is preventing the script from continuing to run, breaking the page.

How should I refactor line 56 to work with PHP8?

Comment: Which is line 56? You could use `$round ?? []`

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't think that `$round` is the problem here may be , `$drivers_race_result_array[$driver_id]` or `$shared_drivers[$driver_id]`

Comment: which line is 56, throwing the error? We can't see your line numbers.

Comment: Line 56 starts with: `if (array_key_exists($round, $shared_drivers[$driver_id]))`

Comment: @angel.bonev I believe the issue is with `$shared_drivers[$driver_id]` as this is Argument #2 on Line 56.

Comment: Indeed it would be. So the error tells you that `$shared_drivers[$driver_id]` is null. We can't see how you populate those variables so we can't know why it was null when the system isn't expecting it to be. Is it normal for it to sometimes be null? If so then simply check bfeore using it with isset() or ??. If not, then do some debugging and fix the issue.

Comment: PHP 8 didn't break your code. The code was already broken, PHP 8 only revealed the problem. Earlier PHP versions could also reveal it but you have probably hidden all warning and notices. Some of them were promoted to errors in PHP 8 because this is what they are: errors. _"Undefined array key"_ means that the code wants to read a value that does not exist. Nobody has written anything at array key 1981 but at some point the code wants to read that value. _"Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given"_ is even worse - `array_key_exists()` is used with a value that is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isset()` instead, as it won't throw an error at any nesting level:

```php
if (isset($shared_drivers[$driver_id][$round])) {
```

Keep in mind that `isset()` will return `false` if the value is `null` though, but I don't think it's a concern in your case.

Answer (score 0):

[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) expect second parameter to be an array you are passing `null`

First solution is to check if the second parameter is an array you can do that with is_array like that :

```php
if (isset($shared_drivers[$driver_id]) 
&& is_array($shared_drivers[$driver_id]) 
&& array_key_exists($round, $shared_drivers[$driver_id])) {
```

Or you can use [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) to change that null with empty array

```php
if (array_key_exists($round, $shared_drivers[$driver_id]??[])) {
```

Comment: Your first snippet will throw a warning if `$shared_drivers[$driver_id]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the outer array key exists first and that this value is an array, stepping into the array levels through the if statement:

```
if ( is_array($shared_drivers)
     && array_key_exists($driver_id, $shared_drivers) 
     && is_array($shared_drivers[$driver_id]) 
     && array_key_exists($round, $shared_drivers[$driver_id]) ){
```

This means that if the $shared_drivers[$driver_id] doesn't exist or is not an array the `IF` statement will abort before testing an invalid array reference ( `$shared_drivers[$driver_id]`)   .

If you're certain that `$shared_drivers` is an array and exist at this point, you can streamline the above code by removing the first argument.